# Problema con el envio de archivo por medio de ajaxFormData

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Buenas, tengo un problema en cuanto a la manera que envió valores de archivo, como uso ajax en jquery y la libreria jquery-formdata, me sale el error de `TypeError: 'slice' called on an object that does not implement interface Blob.` creo que es por que todo esos valores de los campos los almaceno como un objeto JSON, ademas que uso laravel para guardar las imagenes, o almenos eso se supone:

```
function FormInfo()
{
    var valor = $("#addUserForm").serialize();
    var json = {};

    var datos = valor.split("&");

    datos.forEach(function(element, index) {
        var info = element.split("=");
        json[""+info[0]] = info[1];
    });

    json["avatar"] = document.getElementById('plox').files[0];

    return json;
}
```

Este es el codigo con el cual obtengo los valores de los input y los paso a un json al igual que agrego el valor del archivo.

```
$("#addUserForm").submit(function (event) {
    //Ocultando todos los mensajes de error
    $('.chip').hide();

    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxFormData({
        type: "post",
        dataType: "html",
        url: 'users/add',
        contentType: "multipart/form-data",
        data : FormInfo(),
        success: function (response) {
            $("#addUser").modal('close');
            $("#cont-users").addClass('formSubmitted');
            Materialize.toast('Registro ingresado', 3000, 'rounded');
        }
```

Y esta de aqui es el codigo por el cual envio los datos, y esta es la linea de codigo del controlador de usuario en laravel que me da error:

```
$request->file('avatar')->store('public');
```

Asi es la etiqueta form

```
<form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/add" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="addUserForm"><input name="_token" value="kl5DY0aNK0mUt3lR9pGnoeEX8GOlPhdLJkSSh0hd" type="hidden">
```

Comment: Simplemente envía un `FormData`; no puedes enviar binarios en un JSON. `data: new FormData(form)`; donde `form` es el formulario a enviar por AJAX: `const form = document.getElementById('#addUserForm');`.

Comment: Bueno al hacer al pie como me dices me lanza este error: TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

Comment: Perdón, en el `document.getElementById` elimina el gato (`#`).

Comment: const form = document.getElementById('addUserForm');
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxFormData({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html",
            url: 'users/add',
            data : new FormData(form),          Bueno algo asi poseo mi codigo, y ahora me sale el error: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

Comment: Añade estas propiedades al ajax: `processData: false,
    contentType: false`

Comment: Gracias, ya esta, todo bien

Comment: Añado mi respuesta para que la marques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes enviar archivos binarios por medio de JSON; lo que debes hacer es crear un objeto `FormData` con los datos del formulario y enviar este objeto por AJAX.

```
data: new FormData($('#addUserForm')[0]),
```

Así mismo debes establecer `processData` en false:

```
processData: false,
```

De la documentación de jQuery:

> **processData (default: true)**
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object
>   (technically, anything other than a string) **will be processed and
>   transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"**. If you want to send a
>   DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

Por defecto, el objeto pasado en `data` es transformado en una query string; esto por supuesto no funcionará con archivos binarios ya que debe enviarse como tal. Respecto a `contentType` puedes eliminarla o establecerla en `false` para que lleve un mime automático.